# Python JWT auth token does not authorize with django jwt api

Tags: python, django, authentication, jwt

i am trying to call my jwt authenticated django api that lives on an EC2 instance from my home laptop. the API will return me a auth key but when i try to use the auth key it tells me im not authorized. I have provided an example of the various methods i have tried to use to get this to work.

is there anything specifically i am doing wrong in this code that would warrant my code to consistently return 401 error? when asking for an authenticated API with a JWT token is there anything specifically i need to do or a specific way i need to set my headers so that i can get a value to return? or does this look like an issue with the backend?

```
import requests
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
import jwt
from requests_jwt import JWTAuth, payload_method
import json


def tryme(chats, payload, jwt): 
    #method1
    res = requests.post(chats, json=payload)
    print res.status_code
    # error 401

    # method2
    req = requests.get(chats, params=payload)
    print req.status_code
    # error 401

    # method3
    req = Request(chats)
    req.add_header('Authorization', 'Token token={}'.format(auth['token']))
    req.add_header('content-type', 'application/json')
    res = urlopen(req)
    print res.status_code
    # error 401

    #method4
    token = JWTAuth(jwt['token'])
    out = requests.get(chats, auth=token)
    print out.status_code
    # error 401

    out = requests.post(chats, auth=token)
    print out.status_code
    # error 401


def main():
    payload = {
        'username': 'testuser',
        'password': 'test1234'
    }
    base_url = 'https://www.example.com/api/v1/'
    api_auth = base_url + 'api-token-auth/'
    chats = base_url + 'chats/'
    auth = json.loads(requests.post(api_auth, json=payload).content)
    # returns auth token

    payload = {'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format(auth['token']), 'content-type': 'application/json'}
    tryme(chats, payload, auth)
    payload = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(auth['token']), 'content-type': 'application/json'}
    tryme(chats, payload, auth)
    payload = {'Authorization': 'JWT {}'.format(auth['token']), 'content-type': 'application/json'}
    tryme(chats, payload, auth)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Default header scheme in Django JWT is `Authorization: JWT <token>`. In method 3, you can use that.

Comment: perfect. i will see about refining that. if it works i will let you know and you can create a answer for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was solved. however i upgraded to python3.

```
  import requests
  import urllib3
  urllib3.disable_warnings()
  payload = {
        'username': 'testuser',
        'password': 'test1234'
    }
    base_url = 'https://www.example.com/api/v1/'
    api_auth = base_url + 'api-token-auth/'
    chats = base_url + 'chats/'

    # get jwt token from login credentials
    auth = json.loads(requests.post(api_auth, json=payload).content)['token']

    # correctly format the call which was my primary issue above.
    payload = {'Authorization': 'JWT {}'.format(auth)}

    # in python3 use urllib3.
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    res = http.request('GET', chats, headers=payload)
    print(res.data)
```

in python2:

```
   import requests
   payload = {
        'username': 'testuser',
        'password': 'test1234'
    }
    base_url = 'https://www.example.com/api/v1/'
    api_auth = base_url + 'api-token-auth/'
    chats = base_url + 'chats/'

    # get jwt token from login credentials
    auth = json.loads(requests.post(api_auth, json=payload).content)['token']

    # correctly format the call which was my primary issue above.
    payload = {'Authorization': 'JWT {}'.format(auth)}

    # make sure you are using the right request (GET vs POST)
    out = requests.get(chats, headers=token)
    print out.content
```